# How to use my view helpers in my ActionMailer views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use the methods I defined in `app/helpers/annotations_helper.rb` in my ReportMailer views (`app/views/report_mailer/usage_report.text.html.erb`). How do I do this?

Based on [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_mailer_basics.html) it seems like the [`add_template_helper(helper_module)`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_mailer_basics.html#using-action-mailer-helpers) method might do what I want, but I can't figure out how to use it.

(BTW, is there a reason you get access to a different set of helpers in mailer views? This is pretty annoying.)

Comment: similar one - http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/highlight-changes-being-made-on-activerecord-object-inside-mail/

Answer (score 343, accepted):

In the mailer class that you are using to manage your emails:

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  add_template_helper(AnnotationsHelper)

  ...
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in this case (Rails 3.2.8): I have a method defined in ApplicationController and make it a helper by helper_method :my_helper_wannabe, but the method "my_helper_wannabe" doesn't become available in mailer.

Comment: See Duke's answer below for how to handle in Rails 3.

Comment: This worked for me in Rails 3.2.13. One thing to note: I needed to restart my server before the change went into affect.

Comment: I thought these were supposed to be automatically included in Rails 4?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#using-action-mailer-helpers

Comment: Works in Rails 3.2.18 without restart.

Comment: This is an ancient answer but just chiming in to say this worked in Rails 5.2

Comment: In rails 5 you can just add "helper :helpername" right after class name

Comment: This finally breaks in Rails 6.1.0.rc1 

Comment: This doesn't work in 6.1. For Rails 6.1, use Duke's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416978/how-to-use-my-view-helpers-in-my-actionmailer-views/6393071#6393071 with ```helper :helpername```.

Answer (score 167):

In Rails 3, just use the helper method at the top of your ActionMailer class:

```
helper :mail   # loads app/helpers/mail_helper.rb & includes MailHelper
```

I just passed in a block, since I only need it in the one Mailer:

```
helper do
  def host_url_for(url_path)
    root_url.chop + url_path
  end
end
```

(be sure to set config.action_mailer.default_url_options.)

(and if you use url_for, be sure to pass in :only_path => false)

Comment: This works, but feels akward to re-specify helpers already defined in ApplicationController to individual ActionMailer classes as well.  ActionMailer extends ActionController so they come from a common hierarchy.  More of a comment on Rails than your solution...

Comment: And if the helper is in a namespace you can do
`helper :'namespace/mail'`

Comment: if the helper is in a namespace it also accepts just a string (instead of a symbol) `helper 'namespace/mail'`

Comment: Works on Rails 5.2!

Comment: How do you do this when the ActionMailer class is buried in a gem, such as Devise? Putting `<% helper :mail %>` at the top of the mailer view fails with `undefined method 'helper'`. Ideally there would be a way of setting `helper :mail` for *all* Action Mailer mailers…

Comment: Works on Rails 7.0 !

Answer (score 31):

(This is an old question but Rails has evolved so I'm sharing what works for me in Rails 5.2.)

Typically you might want to use a custom view helper in rendering the subject line of an email as well as the HTML. In the case where the view helper is in **app/helpers/application_helper.rb** as follows:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def mydate(time, timezone)
    time.in_time_zone(timezone).strftime("%A %-d %B %Y")
  end

end
```

I can create a dynamic email subject line and template which both use the helper but I need to tell Rails to use the ApplicationHelper explicitly in **apps/mailer/user_mailer.rb** in two different ways, as you can see in the second and third lines here:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  include ApplicationHelper  # This enables me to use mydate in the subject line
  helper :application  # This enables me to use mydate in the email template (party_thanks.html.erb)

  def party_thanks
    @party = params[:party]
    mail(to: 'user@domain.com',
    subject: "Thanks for coming on #{mydate(@party.created_at, @party.timezone)}")
  end

end
```

I should mention that these two lines work just as well so choose one or the other:

```
helper :application

add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)
```

FWIW, the email template at **app/views/user_mailer/party_thanks.html.erb** looks like this:

```
<p>
  Thanks for coming on <%= mydate(@party.created_at, @party.timezone) %>
</p>
```

And the **app/controller/party_controller.rb** controller looks like this

```
class PartyController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    ...
    UserMailer.with(party: @party).party_thanks.deliver_later
    ...
  end
end
```

I have to agree with OP (@Tom Lehman) and @gabeodess that this all feels quite convoluted given https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#using-action-mailer-helpers so perhaps I am missing something...

Answer (score 29):

For all mailers in Rails 3 (setting "application" helper):

```
# config/application.rb:
...
config.to_prepare do
  ActionMailer::Base.helper "application"
end
```

Comment: NOT true - `helper :application` works fine in Rails 4.2.1.

Comment: Works fine even for own email templates for `devise`. `helper :application` does not work in this case.

Comment: not working for 4.2.5.1  -- `include ApplicationHelper` did work

Answer (score 27):

For Ruby on Rails 4, I had to do 2 things:

(1) As [Duke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393071/2700898) already said, if the helper you want to add is `UsersHelper` for example, then add

```
helper :users
```

to the derived `ActionMailer` class (e.g. `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`)

(2) After that, I got a new error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host
parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true)
```

To fix this, add the line

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }
```

to each of the `config/environments/*.rb` files. For `config/environments/production.rb`, replace `localhost` with a more appropriate host for the production helper-generated urls.

---

Q: For #2, why does the mail view need this information, and the regular views do not?

A: Because the regular views don't need to know the `host`, since all generated links are served from the host they link to. Links that show up in emails are not served from the same host (unless you are linking to `hotmail.com` or `gmail.com`, etc.)

Comment: What about composed names ? `User::ComposedHelper`

Answer (score 23):

You can just add in your mailer

```
helper :application
```

or whatever helper you need

Comment: this is a duplicate of an earlier response - @Shevaun

Comment: Works on Rails 5.2!

Comment: Works in Rails 6.0

Comment: Works for me in Rails 6.1.1.

Answer (score 9):

This is what I did in rails 6

```rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'community@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'

  # Add whatever helper you want
  helper :application  

end
```

Answer (score 7):

in my case for Rails4, i do like this:

```
# app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  add_template_helper ApplicationHelper
  ...
end
```

and

```
# app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
class AccountMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def some_method(x, y)
  end
end
```

so that you do not have to specify `add_template_helper` everywhere.