# Using helpers in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I access helpers within ActionMailer from ones I have created?

I have tried: [How to use my view helpers in my ActionMailer views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416978/how-to-use-my-view-helpers-in-my-actionmailer-views) for my own created helper but didn't work. Any advise?

Answer (score 8):

This has worked for me in the past in Rails 3:

```
class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :application, :orders, :products
  ...
end
```

My custom helpers are obviously orders and products.