# Adding TextHelper to UserMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, helper

This question is related to: [How to use my view helpers in my ActionMailer views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416978/how-to-use-my-view-helpers-in-my-actionmailer-views)

I have a `UserMailer.rb` and I am trying to add `TextHelper` so I can use `pluralize(@x, "x")`. I've tried a few things but none seem to work:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  1. helper :text
  2. add_template_helper(TextHelper)

3. application.rb
  config.to_prepare do
    ActionMailer::Base.helper "text"
  end
```

Do you know how I can get pluralize to work in my e-mails? Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

That's how it worked for me:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  def notify(alarms)
    mail(:subject => "#{alarms.size} new #{pluralize(alarms.size, 'alarm')}", ...
  end
end
```