# delayed_job and method from the helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, delayed-job, actionview

I have problem in my application with using helpers in email templates. In my application I have implemented "money-rails" to handle payment in other currencies.I have the following helper:

```
module CurrencyHelper

  # overriding std rails helper to use 'money' gem methods
  def number_to_currency(money, options = {})
    return '-' unless money
    currency = options.fetch(:currency, current_currency)
    date = options.fetch(:date, nil)
    should_reload = if date && !money.currency.eql?(currency)
                      ExchangeRatesManager.new(date: date).call
                    end

    money_in_currency = money.exchange_to(currency)
    ExchangeRatesManager.new.call if should_reload # should rollback to current exchange rates

    humanized_money_with_symbol(money_in_currency)
  end

end
```

And now I use it in my email mailers templates. When I send mail not through delayed_job everything is ok:

```
UserMailer.reservation_confirmation_link(@reservation).deliver
```

but when I send email through delayed_job:
`RentalOfficeMailer.delay.reservation_summary(@reservation)` it not load this overwrited number_to_currency method and it not shows me proper currency. 
Thank's in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this do it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416978/how-to-use-my-view-helpers-in-my-actionmailer-views

Comment: Seems like your helper is not getting loaded, or loaded in the wrong order.  Have you tried just requiring it in the mailer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem where helpers are not loading in background, I solved this by calling helper method this way, in your case u can do:

```
Class.new.extend(CurrencyHelper).number_to_currency(money, {})
```