# ruby on rails - use a helper in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a html.erb file used for an email template.
Is there any way to include a helper module and use it's methods within this file?
Something like:

a `mails_helper.rb` file:

```
module MailsHelper
  def mail_to
    "foo"
  end
end
```

and in `mail_template.html.erb`:

```
<% include MailsHelper %>
  <h2> This mail was sent to: <%= mail_to %> </h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `helper :mail` to the top of your ActionMailer derived class
ex:- *app/mailers/mails_mailer.rb*

```
class MailMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :mails

  ...
end
```

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416978/how-to-use-my-view-helpers-in-my-actionmailer-views) answer

Answer (score 0):

Name the helper file with same prefix as the ActionMailer's file name.

For example:
mailer: `users_mailer.rb` helper: `users_mailer_helper.rb`

According to the ruby on rails naming conventions - any view rendered by `UsersMailer` would have access to your helper methods.