# Include application_helper.rb in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get access to some of my `application_helper` methods within my mailer, but nothing seems to be working from these SO posts:

[View Helpers in Mailers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416978/how-to-use-my-view-helpers-in-my-actionmailer-views)

[Access Helpers from mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937208/access-helpers-from-mailer)

In `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` I have the following:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def get_network_hosts
    .. stuff get get a @network_hosts object
  end
end
```

In my mailer at `app/mailers/user_notifier.rb` I have the following:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Support <support@me.co>"
  add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)

  def trial_notifier(user)
    get_network_hosts
    @user = user
    @total = user.company.subscription.per_device_charge * @network_hosts.count
    if @total < 501
      @message = "You'd pay #{@total}/month if you converted to full-access now!"
    else
      @message = "You'd pay #{@total}/month if you converted to full-access now, but we have a better deal for you!"
    end

    @url = edit_user_registration_url
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'What's up?')
  end
end
```

In my mailer I've tried all of the suggestions in the above SO posts, but I'm still getting this error:

```
 `NameError: undefined local variable or method `get_network_hosts' for #<UserMailer:0x007fe756c67c18`>
```

I'm currently using Rails 4.1.7.

So what do I have to actually do to be able to use my application_helper methods within a mailer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this as following:

In your `mailer` at `app/mailers/user_notifier.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Support <support@me.co>"
  helper :application
```

or you can try this:

```
helper ApplicationHelper
```

Comment: I tried that as well as `include ApplicationHelper` and neither worked.

Comment: @Godzilla74 i've just updated my answer, you can check it again.